# How to use custom input type in graphql-compose?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-compose-mongoose, graphql-compose

I'm using mongodb and graphql-compose-mongoose in order to generate the Graphql schema. However I'm adding authentication mutations and I want to add graphql input for one of the queries. I saw in the documentation that `args.filter` can receive an input:

```
CityTC.addResolver({
  kind: 'query',
  name: 'findMany',
  args: {
    filter: `input CityFilterInput {
      code: String!
    }`,
    limit: {
      type: 'Int',
      defaultValue: 20,
    },
    skip: 'Int',
    // ... other args if needed
  },
  type: [CityTC], // array of cities
  resolve: async ({ args, context }) => {
    return context.someCityDB
      .findMany(args.filter)
      .limit(args.limit)
      .skip(args.skip);
  },
});
```

However I'm not using any filter. I want to create an input like this:

```
const AuthPayloadTC = schemaComposer.createObjectTC({
  name: 'AuthPayloadTC',
  fields: {
      jwtToken: 'String!'
  }
});

AuthPayloadTC.addResolver({
  name: 'userConnectData',
  type: AuthPayloadTC,
  args: `input {
    accessToken String!
    provider String!
  }`,
  resolve: async ({ source, args, context, info }) => {
      const { accessToken, provider } = args;
      return {
          jwtToken: '12345678'
      }
  }
})
```

This doesn't work because my input is not parsed to a the kind of object that `args` field expects. I did notice that graphql-compose exposes [InputTypeComposer](https://graphql-compose.github.io/docs/api/InputTypeComposer.html) however I couldn't any example on how to use it in a resolver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through some trial and error I figured out this out:

```
import { schemaComposer, toInputObjectType } from 'graphql-compose'

const InputTC = schemaComposer.createObjectTC({
  name: 'UserConnectDataInput',
  fields: {
    accessToken: 'String!'
  }
});

const InputITC = toInputObjectType(InputTC);

AuthPayloadTC.addResolver({
  name: 'userConnectData',
  type: AuthPayloadTC,
  args: {
    input: InputITC
  },
  resolve: async ({ source, args, context, info }) => {
      const { accessToken, provider, email } = args;
      return {
          jwtToken: '12345678'
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: This can be shortened by using `schemaComposer.createInputTC({...})`. As you perhaps know, you also do not need to define it with `const InputITC` - you can just use `args: {input: 'UserConnectDataInput'}`.